# optimize large csv file writer - large table datareader using TPL PLINQ

Tags: c#, sql, csv, task-parallel-library, plinq

Any tips on how I can optimize below further using TPL and/or PLINQ.

Below code runs on a background worker

```
Read a large table using sql reader 
Open stream writer to write a large csv file
while (reader.read())
{
   massage the data, parse data from columns etc. 
   create csv string to write to file
   write csv line to file
}
close reader
close file
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you suck the entire dataset into your application (or at least a large part of the dataset?)  That would allow you to run the `massage the data, parse data from columns etc.` step in parallel on several records at the time.  Otherwise you're kind of SOL as I assume the writes need to happen in particular order.

Comment: No, too large to load entire dataset. thx

Answer (score 0):

You might find better performance by writing the csv line data to a StringBuilder (I.E., in memory) then writing the contents out to your csv file. I would suggest using both methods along with a memory profiler like ANTS or the JetBrains product.

Comment: Does the stream writer take a string builder ? I will look into this and also profile as you mentioned. thx

Comment: This is asking for out of memory exception. He could just increase buffer size for his FileStream instead, to make it both cleaner and more controlled. But to be honest I very much doubt CSV writing has any impact on the performance here.

Answer (score 0):

define "optimize further"... Do you want more speed or less memory use?

Assuming above pseudo code is correctly implemented then memory use should be already pretty minimal.

Speed? Based on the statement that that you are working with a **large** data set, then the data reader would be your biggest source of slowness. So if you really wanted to use parallel processing, then you'd have to fragment your data set (presumably open multiple readers?)

But then again, you are already running it in a background worker, so does it really matter?

Comment: I like the idea of multiple readers where one reader reads top down and other reader reads bottom up (using order by asc desc trick on the two readers..) That way I can meet somewhere in the middle and get this task split up. I will check my logic to see if this is possible. thanks